# Counting divisibility from 1 to 1000

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

Of the integers $1, 2, 3, ..., 1000$, how many are **not** divisible by $3$, $5$, or $7$?

The way I went about this was

$$\text{floor}(1000/3) + \text{floor}(1000/5) + \text{floor}(1000/7)-\text{floor}(1000/(3\cdot5)) - \text{floor}(1000/(3\cdot7))-\text{floor}(1000/(5\cdot7))+\text{floor}(1000/(3\cdot5\cdot7))$$

which resulted in $543$ and then I subtracted that from $1000$ to get $457$.

I do not have an answer key so I was wondering if that was the right approach to the question.
Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html  or http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/InclusionExclusion.shtml

Comment: For a check, you could make a spreadsheet with column a having rows $1$ through $1000$ and in the next column put =mod(a1,3)*mod(a1,5)*mod(a1,7), copy down, and count the non-zeros.

Answer (score 3):

Your result of 457 is correct.

The different sets of numbers as table:

[image]

And as [diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_diagram):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and graph. I'm glad I was right!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use the Inclusion/Exclusion principle.  Let us first count how many numbers *are* divisible by $3$, $5$, or $7$.  Let set $X$ be the set of all such numbers.

Let $A$ = {Numbers divisible by $3$}
Let $B$ = {Numbers divisible by $5$}
Let $C$ = {Numbers divisible by $7$}

By the inclusion/exclusion principle:

$|X| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A\cap B| - |A\cap C| - |B\cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$.  Then, of course, the answer you're looking for will be $1000-|X|$.

I'll leave the implementation of this up to you.  :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help